# Convert HMM /HHMM time column to timestamp in R

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion

I am new here please be gentle ;)

I have two time columns in a dataframe in R that uses the HMM /HHMM format as a numeric. For example, 03:13 would be 313 and 14:14 would be 1414. An example would be sched_arr_time and sched_dep_time in the nycflights13 package.

I need to calculate the time difference in minutes. My SQL knowledge tells me I would substring this with a case when and then glue it back together as a time format somehow but I was hoping there is a more elegant way in R to deal with this?

Many thanks for your help!

This would explain the data:

```
library(nycflights13)
flights %>% select(sched_dep_time, sched_arr_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert to time class with `as.ITime` after changing the format to `HH:MM` with `str_pad` and `str_replace`, and then take the difference using `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
flights %>% 
     head %>%
     select(sched_dep_time, sched_arr_time) %>% 
     mutate_all(~ str_pad(., width = 4, pad = 0) %>%
                   str_replace(., '^(..)', '\\1:') %>% 
                   as.ITime) %>%
    mutate(diff = difftime(sched_arr_time, sched_dep_time, unit = 'min'))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  sched_dep_time sched_arr_time diff    
#  <ITime>        <ITime>        <drtn>  
#1 05:15:00       08:19:00       184 mins
#2 05:29:00       08:30:00       181 mins
#3 05:40:00       08:50:00       190 mins
#4 05:45:00       10:22:00       277 mins
#5 06:00:00       08:37:00       157 mins
#6 05:58:00       07:28:00        90 mins
```

---

If we want to add a 'Date' as well, then we

```
library(lubridate)
flights %>%
   head %>% 
   select(sched_dep_time, sched_arr_time)  %>% 
   mutate_all(~ str_pad(., width = 4, pad = 0) %>%
               str_replace("^(..)(..)", "\\1:\\2:00") %>% 
               str_c(Sys.Date(), ., sep=' ') %>%
               ymd_hms) %>%
   mutate(diff = difftime(sched_arr_time, sched_dep_time, unit = 'min'))
```

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks! It does not work properly for times that go overnight. Is there a way around this (by adding a date maybe)?

Comment: @FXMRZ Yes,  you can do `hms` `flights %>% 
+      head %>%
+      select(sched_dep_time, sched_arr_time) %>% 
+      mutate_all(~ str_pad(., width = 4, pad = 0) %>%
+                    str_replace(., '^(..)(..)', '\\1:\\2:00') %>% as.hms) %>% mutate(diff = difftime(sched_arr_time, sched_dep_time, unit = 'min'))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `strptime`

```
as_time <- function(x)
    as.POSIXct(strptime(if_else(nchar(x) == 3, paste0("0", x), as.character(x)), "%H%M"))

flights %>%
    select(sched_dep_time, sched_arr_time) %>%
    mutate(diff_in_mins = difftime(as_time(sched_arr_time), as_time(sched_dep_time), "mins"))
## A tibble: 336,776 x 3
#   sched_dep_time sched_arr_time diff_in_mins
#            <int>          <int> <drtn>
# 1            515            819 184 mins
# 2            529            830 181 mins
# 3            540            850 190 mins
# 4            545           1022 277 mins
# 5            600            837 157 mins
# 6            558            728  90 mins
# 7            600            854 174 mins
# 8            600            723  83 mins
# 9            600            846 166 mins
#10            600            745 105 mins
## … with 336,766 more rows
```